# C++: How to split a string by ' ' (space), but not by '\ ' (backslash space)?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, split

I'm surprised there is no this question already despite how popular this task might be. Is it possible to do it without writing your own parser? Two or more whitespaces in a row must be skipped. Here's my solution if not

```cpp
vector<string> split_with_backslash(const string &s)
{
    vector<string> ret;
    const char *ps = s.c_str();
    while (*ps++) {
        std::stringstream ss;
        switch (*ps) {
        default:
            ss << *ps;
            break;
        case ' ': case '\t': case '\n':
            ret.push_back(ss.str());
            ss.str(string());
            ss.clear();
            break;
        case '\\':
            if (!(*++ps == ' ' || *ps == '\t' || *ps == '\n'))
                --ps;
            break;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

I'm bad with cpp iterators, so I've used `c_str()`

**EDIT:** Adding the `wordexp` example for @MarekR. It is relevant to the question, because `wordexp` nicely handles the quotation marks/backspaces, but not the special symbols below.

Here I'm preparing the pipeline for execution. This way I get rid of the '|' sign, which `wordexp` doesn't eat, but there's still `<>&` (I don't consider `&` for simplicity.

```cpp
vector<string> subcommands;
boost::split(subcommands, cpp_buf, boost::is_any_of("|"));
wordexp_t res;
switch (wordexp(subcommands.back().c_str(), &res, 0)) {
    case 0:
        break;
    case WRDE_NOSPACE:
        wordfree(&res);
    default:
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: What should happen if there are two-or-more spaces in a row?

Comment: @Eljay They must be skipped

Comment: Question is why? Why do you need this feature, please provide more context. Is this some parsing of command line? There are some ready solution (system specific) to handle command line strings. What is you target OS?

Comment: @MarekR Yes, I'm making my own linux-like shell. I used the `wordexp` library to do the most of the work, but now that I'm implementing pipes, redirection, etc. I need to do some parsing myself before I use it (`wordexp` doesn't eat `<|>;&`)

Comment: So show code how you used `wordexp` and explain problem you have with it by [edit] your question. I'm sure after that you will get better answer. I'm pretty sure you are reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @MarekR Added the code. If any of the subcommands contains a special symbol, `wordexp` will return an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have presented is *so close* to doing what you want it to do; just one subtle change required: move the `std::stringstream ss;` declaration to **before** (i.e. *outside of*) the `while` loop. As it stands, a new (empty) `stringstream` object is being created on each and every iteration of that loop.

However, there is a (possibly) easier way to achieve the same, by using an 'escape flag' to signal that any space is preceded by a backslash, and only pushing your substring to the result vector if that flag is false:

```cpp
vector<string> split_with_backslash(const string& s)
{
    vector<string> ret;
    bool escape = false;
    std::stringstream ss{};
    for (auto ps : s) { // "ps" is now a simple "char" but I've kept the name
        switch (ps) {
            default:
                ss << ps;
                escape = false;
                break;
            case ' ': case '\t': case '\n':
                if (!escape) {
                    ret.push_back(ss.str());
                    ss.str(string());
                    ss.clear();
                }
                else {
                    ss << ps; // If you want the escaped space to be included in the string
                    escape = false;
                }
                break;
            case '\\':
                escape = true;
                break;
       // The following alternative "case '\\'" block will allow input of
       // escaped backslash characters (if that's required) ...
       /*   case '\\':
                if (escape) {
                    ss << ps;
                    escape = false;
                }
                else {
                    escape = true;
                }
                break; */
        }
    }
    if (!ss.str().empty()) ret.push_back(ss.str()); // Don't forget final sub-string!
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Yes, totally forgot. Can't we just get rid of clearing the stream by moving it back into the loop?

Comment: But all the time it is declared inside the loop, it can't maintain its value across different runs of that loop.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Forgot once again

Comment: Won't handle the `R"(this is a\ \\slash\\ t\e\s\t)"` case, unless the escaping backslash character itself is disallowed from the input.  Only relevant if that is a concern for the text to be split.

Comment: @Eljay Indeed (see edit). There was also an error in not saving any 'leftover' end-of-input substring.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version that lets you avoid allocation (except if you use `split_all`), and handles escaped backslashes as well, and includes testcases:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// Needed for C++17 compatibility.
// In C++20, just use the string_view constructor.
template<class It>
std::string_view string_view_from_it(It b, It e)
{
    return std::string_view(&*b, e - b);
}

std::string_view skip_space(std::string_view s)
{
    auto it = s.begin();
    for (; it != s.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (!std::isspace(*it))
            break;
    }
    return string_view_from_it(it, s.end());
}
std::pair<std::string_view, std::string_view> split_one(std::string_view s)
{
    bool escaped = false;
    auto it = s.begin();
    for (; it != s.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (escaped)
        {
            escaped = false;
            continue;
        }
        if (*it == '\\')
            escaped = true;
        else if (std::isspace(*it))
            break;
    }
    return {string_view_from_it(s.begin(), it), string_view_from_it(it, s.end())};
}

std::vector<std::string_view> split_all(std::string_view s)
{
    std::vector<std::string_view> v;

    s = skip_space(s);
    while (!(s = skip_space(s)).empty())
    {
        auto pair = split_one(s);
        v.push_back(pair.first);
        s = pair.second;
    }
    return v;
}


#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    for (std::string_view s : {
            "",
            "  ",
            " a b ",
            "hello\\ world",
            " \\ \\\\ \\  \\",
    })
    {
        auto v = split_all(s);
        std::cout << "split('" << s << "') = [";

        bool first = true;
        for (auto s : v)
        {
            if (!first)
                std::cout << ", ";
            first = false;
            std::cout << "'" << s << "'";
        }
        std::cout << "]" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

That said, I would prefer a real lexer at this point, and actually *handle* the backslashes (including "backslash at end of input").

I also prefer to forbid all control characters other than newline - notably CR and TAB - or at least normalize them in an earlier phase.

Comment: That's interesting. And I suppose we can't use `std::move` while pushing into the vector because it would mess the view?

Comment: No, nothing would be messed up, but there's no point. Since `string_view` is `TriviallyCopyable`, copying and moving do the same thing.